# How to parse json with ijson and python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have JSON data as an array of dictionaries which comes as the request payload.

```
[ 
    { "Field1": 1, "Feld2": "5" },
    { "Field1": 3, "Feld2": "6" }
]
```

I tried `ijson.items(f, '')` which yields the entire JSON object as one single item. Is there a way I can iterate the items inside the array one by one using ijson?

Here is the sample code I tried which is yielding the JSON as one single object.

```
f = open("metadatam1.json")
objs = ijson.items(f, '')
for o in objs:
     print str(o) + "\n"

[{'Feld2': u'5', 'Field1': 1}, {'Feld2': u'6', 'Field1': 3}]
```

Comment: Please add your code, demonstrating how it "yields entire json as one single item"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `ijson`, but reading some of its code it looks like calling `items` with a prefix of `"item"` should work to get the items of the array, rather than the top-level object:

```
for item in ijson.items(f, "item"):
    # do stuff with the item dict
```

Comment: This just spits out the following error: ```TypeError: can't concat bytes to str```

Comment: @JeremyCraigMartinez: There's no way I can guess where that exception is coming from with just the exception text. I suggest asking a question of your own, and including your code and a full traceback.

Comment: Sorry, just disregard that comment. I started just googling that along with ijson and found what I was looking for pretty quickly

Comment: This about drove me crazy, this answers "how to iterate over a JSON array in ijson" - which isn't exactly straightforward at a glance haha (vs. getting one big list item yielded)